# Drawing a shield-like figure in CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm looking for a way to draw a shield-like figure in CSS. Roughly the bottom half of the figure should be a half circle, while the upper half should be part of an upside-down triangle / trapezoid. So where the half-circle ends, it should continue upwards (with a small slope). The top should be flat.

I know how to draw a full circle with `border-radius: 50%` and I know how to draw an upside-down triangle with transparent borders in CSS, but somehow I never get them to line-up properly.

Something like this, except for the bottom black part. The yellow and top black part should both be the same color.

[image: shield example]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried already?

Comment: can you add a picture?

Comment: Added a picture. I'll see if I can extract the code, but the size is based on elements around it (i.e. all percentages), so give me some time.

Comment: how about `background-image: url("http://i.stack.imgur.com/rtyFc.png");` :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Soln 1: Perspective

You can use a pseudo element for this, setting it up with perspective and rotation transforms to create the shape.

**Note**

I've set this up using 100px * 100px element, but varying sizes (currently) will require tweaking:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 150px;
  -moz-perspective: 150px;
  -ms-perspective: 150px;
  perspective: 150px;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: -20%;
  position: absolute;
  background: tomato;
  height: 100%;
  width: 140%;
  transform-origin: top right;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-45deg);
  transform: rotateX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

## Soln 2: Borders

you could use borders to create a trapezium shape with a pseudo element, and place it accordingly. However, this leave the same issue as the first solution in terms of scaling (since borders won't accept percentages as width values) - and so again would need to be changed depending on the size.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: -20%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 57px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

## Soln 3: Skewed Elements

```css
div {
  margin: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: -10%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 60%;
  background: tomato;
  transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(10deg);
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: -10%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 60%;
  background: tomato;
  transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: The pseudo-element seems to work really well. Is it true though, that trying to print an HTML page with a pseudo-element from a browser doesn't work?

Comment: It's not the pseudo-element that is not printable, it is the `transform`.

Comment: IDK whether transform is printable or not, but his second method doesn't have transforms.

Comment: Myeah. Second thing is exactly what I used / tried to use the whole time, but indeed the problem is with percentages and the border width.

Comment: @VanderHoorn: Have a look at my third solution: Should possibly meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want something like this? Hopefully that puts you on the right track.

**Updated:**

Can you add a picture and your attempted answer? It would help to put you on the right path.

```
#shield {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid yellow;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
#shield:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px; top: 20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 70px solid yellow;
}
```

**Previous Answer:**

```
#shield {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid yellow;
  border-left: 60px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 60px solid yellow;
  border-top-left-radius: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Not really :/ This is more like a triangle in a circle.
I'm looking for a (larger) triangle over a circle (same color). More like bottom half circle, top half trapezoid. The largest side of the trapezoid should be up and the bottom side of the trapezoid should be the same size as the diameter of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
.shield {
  display: block;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 0;
  position: relative; 
}

.shield:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: black transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 2px 0 2px;
  top: -14px;
  left: -11px;
  width: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, something like this! But then without the part where the circle starts to get upwards.